# HERE Maps JS API v3: `onceEventListener` method bug

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I need to use `onceEventListener` method from an instance of `H.Map` as documented [here](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map.html#h-map__onceeventlistener), but instead it threw me an error saying that `Uncaught TypeError: map.onceEventListener is not a function`. What could be wrong?

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/glenn/rrsnac9u/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the API, try using addEventListner and removeEvent Listner as a work around

```
map.addEventListener('tap', event1, false);
  var event1=function (evt) {
         console.log("executing listner 1");
        map.removeEventListener('tap', event1);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, man! My colleague also suggested the same workaround earlier today. What a shame for HERE. =(

Comment: Regret the inconvenience, the method is not supported and will be removed from documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed seem to be a bug with our APIs. For now, the work around is a good idea, and I have notified the MAPJS team so they can look into the issue. Thanks.